# Import "normal" MongoDB collections into DerbyJS 0.6

Tags: mongodb, derbyjs, racerjs, sharejs, livedb

Same situation like this question, but with current DerbyJS (version 0.6):
[Using imported docs from MongoDB in DerbyJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379276/using-imported-docs-from-mongodb-in-derbyjs)

> I have a MongoDB collection with data that was not saved through my
>   Derby app. I want to query against that and pull it into my Derby app.

Is this still possible?

The accepted answer there links to a dead link. The newest working link would be this: https://github.com/derbyjs/racer/blob/0.3/lib/descriptor/query/README.md

Which refers to the 0.3 branch for Racer (current master version is 0.6).

---

### What I tried

- Searching the internets
- The naïve way:

  ```
  var query = model.query('projects-legacy', { public: true });
  model.fetch(query, function() {
    query.ref('_page.projects');
  })
  ```

  <sup>(doesn't work)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A utility was written for this purpose: https://github.com/share/igor

You may need to modify it to only run against a single collection instead of the whole database, but it essentially goes through every document in the database and modifies it with the necessary livedb metadata and creates a default operation for it as well.

In livedb every collection has a corresponding operations collection, for example `profiles` will have a `profiles_ops` collection which holds all the operations for the profiles.

You will have to convert the collection to use it with Racer/livedb because of the metadata on the document itself.

An alternative if you dont want to convert is to use traditional AJAX/REST to get the data from your mongo database and then just put it in your local model. This will not be real-time or synced to the server but it will allow you to drive your templates from data that you dont want to convert for some reason.